# JMeter Integration With Azure Pipeline and after execution of test got as File size (11956969445) is greater than possible Buffer: 2147483647 bytes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, azure-devops, cicd

A part of JMeter Integration with Azure Pipeline and after execution of test in Azure Pipeline got as **File size (11956969445) is greater than possible Buffer: 2147483647 bytes**.

Is it possible to us to control the log size sent to jmeter [image]

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose what to store in JMeter's [.jtl result file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) by specifying the relevant properties responsible for the [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

In order to [reduce disk IO and file size](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) you should be storing only those metrics which are absolutely required and use CSV format for the output.

The properties can be

1. either put to *user.properties* file
2. or to separate .properties file (you will need to make JMeter aware of this file via [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
3. or you can pass them via -J command-line argument like

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false etc.
   ```

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)